Print out outfit patterns
Downloaded some patterns for making some outfits for my 12 month old daughter, they say they are print out patterns but I'm uncertain how it works. Do I just print it on regular paper?

A well-designed downloadable pattern will always include directions on how to print it.
Many will include a note on the paper size with the listing, as in this example image from Etsy, with the paper size information highlighted. Note that all further example images will come from this pattern.

They may also include the size information in the filenames when downloaded, to help ensure you select the right option when multiple sizes are offered:

They will always include information, either in the instructions or on the printable pattern file, about how to print and assemble the pattern:

Your patterns, if well-designed, will also include this information; this is what you should consult for how to print your patterns.
